# no matching function for call to ‘boost::property_tree::ptree_bad_data::ptree_bad_data()

Tags: c++, boost

I have my custom exception class derived from [boost::property_tree::ptree_bad_data](https://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/property_tree/ptree_bad_data.html) as follows:

```
class MyCustomException : public boost::property_tree::ptree_bad_data
{
    public:
      explicit MyCustomException(const std::string& msg): mMsg(msg) {}
      virtual ~MyCustomException() throw() {}
      virtual const char* what() const throw() { return mMsg.c_str(); }

    private:
      std::string mMsg;
};
```

During compilation I get errors as:

`error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::property_tree::ptree_bad_data::ptree_bad_data()’
       explicit MyCustomException(const std::string& msg): mMsg(msg) {}
                                                                    ^ 
note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
       explicit MyCustomException(const std::string& msg): mMsg(msg) {}
                                                                   ^`

Any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: The code and the error message you show doesn't match. When posting questions about build-errors, use the errors from the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you show us.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have edited the error.

Comment: ptree_bad_data has not default ctor, hence the error. Initialize your base

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation the class `ptree_bad_data` doesn't have parameterless constructor. It has actually single constructor:

```
template<typename T> ptree_bad_data(const std::string &, const T &);
```

So you have to provide these two arguments in your constructor:

```
explicit MyCustomException(const std::string& msg)
    : boost::property_tree::ptree_bad_data(msg, nullptr /* correct data here */)
```

There is also no need for your exception class to store exception message separately. Standard exception classes will do that for you.

Btw, are you sure you want to derive your exception from `ptree_bad_data`?

Comment: Thanks. It worked. The reason was to use more specific exception instead of std::exception. Any particular reason this might be not good idea ?

Comment: @astre then derive from std::exception if you don't have specific reason to derive from `ptree_bad_data` (which you probably don't have if you don't use all its constructor parameters).